# Eclipse Luna Android plugin sdk manager will not open.

Tags: android, eclipse

I've downloaded Java 1.8.0_25 and eclipse Luna 4.4 and installed the Android Plugin by following this

```
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4
```

I've downloaded the Android SDK and placed it at C:\Android.

In eclipse if i go Window ->preferences ->Android

the path is set to C:\Android.

If i then try to open the sdk manager to download all the APIs, eclipse says it is starting the sdk manager but it fails with the following message in the console.

```
[SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in SDK Tools 24.0.0 which makes the SDK Manager not work on some 32-bit Windows systems. When you start Android Studio 1.0.1 you get a balloon saying that Tools 24.0.1 is available; click on it, and then you can install it right from within the IDE (that doesn't use the SDK Manager to do the install). SDK Manager should now work again. If not you can download a fix for the SDK manager directly from 
http://tools.android.com/knownissues 
(see the first issue)

Comment: thanks, i decided to migrate to Android studio anyway.